# Can't push from XCode to Github master branch

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github, push

I created a new `repository` on github, modified the default readme file and then created a development `branch` to work on my project.

I have successfully commited and merged on development branch after it, sending all local modifications to github.

But when I try to `push` my local modifications to the `master` branch, `XCode` returns the following message:

> **The local repository is out of date**
>
> Make sure all changes have been pulled from the remote repository and try again.

And if I try to pull the changes..

[image]

How can I correctly push my project to the master branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must do a `git pull` before you push to the server.
There are updates on the serer which you don't have on your repository.

```
git pull origin <branch
git push origin <branch>
```

When you try to push git verify that the latest commit from the server is in your local branch. if it does not - if you don't have it locally yo will be asked to pull the changes form the server before you can push your updates.

Comment: I`m getting "project-name/master" is not a valid remote branch to pull from

Comment: without the [/]. `git pull origin master`